# ¿Cómo llenar una tabla en Blade con consulta a la base de datos, separar productos y totalizar los mismos?

Tags: postgresql, laravel-blade, blade, laravel-9

Buenas tardes mis estimados,
Tengo una consulta a la base de datos la cual me trae la siguiente información

```
$salesAnalysisBySeller = SaleDetail::where('sale_detail.company', Auth::user()->company)
                ->select('sale_detail.product',
                    'product.pCode',
                    'product.pReference',
                    'product.pName',
                    'seller.name',
                    'seller.identification',
                    'category.cName',
                    'brand.bName',
                    'sale_detail.quantity',
                    'sale_detail.total',
                    'sale_detail.date_expedition',
                )
                ->join('product', 'product.pId', '=', 'sale_detail.product')
                ->join('sale', 'sale.id', '=', 'sale_detail.invoice')
                ->join('seller', 'seller.id', '=', 'sale.seller')
                ->join('category', 'category.cId', '=', 'product.cId')
                ->join('brand', 'brand.bId', '=', 'product.brand')
                ->where('sale.seller', '=', $request->seller)
                ->category($request->category)
                ->brand($request->brand)
                ->orderBy('sale_detail.product', 'ASC')
                ->get();
```

Render de la tabla

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Fecha</th>
        <th>Cod. producto</th>
        <th>Producto</th>
        <th>Categoria</th>
        <th>Cantidad</th>
        <th>Valor</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($saleBySeller as $item)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $item->date_expedition }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->pName }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->pCode }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->cName }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->quantity }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->total }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

| FECHA | COD. PRODUCTO | PRODUCTO | CATEGORIA | CANTIDAD | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-08-01 | 01 | YOI FLORAL GARDEN | FRAGANCIAS | 1 | 15000 |
| 202308-01 | 01 | YOI FLORAL GARDEN | FRAGANCIAS | 2 | 30000 |
| 2023-08-02 | 01 | YOI FLORAL GARDEN | FRAGANCIAS | 1 | 15000 |
| 2023-08-03 | 02 | DESTORNILLADOR ELECTRICO | FERRETERIA | 1 | 45000 |
| 2023-08-03 | 02 | DESTORNILLADOR ELECTRICO | FERRETERIA | 3 | 135000 |
| 2023-08-04 | 03 | SOPLADORA GENERICA | FERRETERIA | 1 | 50000 |

EL asunto es que quiero que cada grupo de productos se totalice la cantidad y el valor total como se muestra a continuación.

| FECHA | COD. PRODUCTO | PRODUCTO | CATEGORIA | CANTIDAD | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-08-01 | 01 | YOI FLORAL GARDEN | FRAGANCIAS | 1 | 15000 |
| 202308-01 | 01 | YOI FLORAL GARDEN | FRAGANCIAS | 2 | 30000 |
| 2023-08-02 | 01 | YOI FLORAL GARDEN | FRAGANCIAS | 1 | 15000 |
|  | 01 | YOI FLORAL GARDEN | TOTALES | 4 | 60000 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2023-08-03 | 02 | DESTORNILLADOR ELECTRICO | FERRETERIA | 1 | 45000 |
| 2023-08-03 | 02 | DESTORNILLADOR ELECTRICO | FERRETERIA | 3 | 135000 |
|  | 02 | DESTORNILLADOR ELECTRICO | TOTALES | 4 | 180000 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2023-08-04 | 03 | SOPLADORA GENERICA | FERRETERIA | 1 | 50000 |
|  | 03 | SOPLADORA GENERICA | TOTALES | 1 | 50000 |

De antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar